# Iterate through URLs and get particular values

Tags: php, url, https, get

My aim is to iterate through some website URLs and save particular data from each page, however, I don't even have idea how to start.

The link is always the same. Only the very last parameter (ID) changes.
It looks like:

```
https://www.test.com/controller-name/06876472
```

The page has such structure:

```
<p>test</p>
<h2>TEST</h2>
```

I'd like to get next 100 `<h2></h2>` elements.
So the loop should stop at 06876571 element.

I've already tried something like this:

```
   <?php

        for($i=06876472; $i<06876572; $i++) {
           $results[]=file_get_contents("https://test.com/controller-name/".$i."");

        }


        print_r($results);

?>
```

This is a secure connection (https).

The error is:

> file_get_contents(url): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

I'd really appreciate if someone could help me.

Comment: That means you're giving an incorrect URL.

Comment: Your `for` loop makes no sense. If you start with `06876472`, it will never be less than `100`.

Comment: Sorry, I've just made a mistake.
The loop should look like 
for($i=06876472; $i<06876572; $i++) {
...
}

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have a leading zero on `$i`. When a number literal begins with `0`, PHP treats it as octal, and the number parser stops reading as soon as it encounters a non-octal digit (`8` and `9` are not octal digits). So `$i = 06876472` is treated as `$i = 6`.

If the number should always be 8 digits long, with leading zeroes, you can use `sprintf()` to format it.

```
for ($i = 6876472; $i < 6876472 + 100; $i++) {
    $url = sprintf("https://test.com/controller-name/%08d", $i);
    $results[] = file_get_contents($url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out these functions in PHP, will put you on the right track:

```
http_build_query()
explod()
foreach()
and finally the global $_GET array
```